# C# - Embed dll in exe - FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, dll, embed, exe, filenotfoundexception

I only want one single file to launch my programm, thatswhy I want to embed my dll in my exe.

I need 2 dll for one it's working.

This is my programm.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _4_Gewinnt___Client {
    static class Program {
        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
            Application.Run(new Client());
        }

        static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {
            string assemblyName = args.Name.Split(',').First();
            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("_4_Gewinnt___Client." + assemblyName + ".dll")) {
                byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I run my application I get a FileNotFoundException.

BTW, build action is set to "embed resource". And reference is set and "Local Copy" is false.
If I set "Local Copy" to "true" everything is working, but I don't want any other files (except the .exe).

I hope you understand everything, my english is not the best :)

Comment: Is the assembly file name is `_4_Gewinnt___Client." + assemblyName + ".dll`?

Comment: The dll's name is: SharpUpdate.dll My namespace is called "_4_Gewinnt___Client"

Comment: And what is the assembly file relative path from project path?

Comment: The path is correct, because one dll works, but the other not!